Problem with npm start inside of .NET Core SPA but not in Angular itself
I use a .NET Core service to host my Angular application as an SPA. When I start my .NET service to host the SPA, everything seems fine, but the console flashes up and closes directly. I was able to get a screenshot with a screen record tool and extract the error message:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\...\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js'

   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
   at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
     code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
     requireStack: []
  }

In my .NET Core console it's just written:
ERR] Couldn't start the SPA development server with command 'npm start'

But when I then run the npm start command in CMD (so not hosting over SPA) it works fine. Also I checked the file which is not found above. The file ng.js exists. I don't understand why it works in CMD but not over SPA.
Environment:
Angular CLI: 15.2.11
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.11
@angular/cli                    15.2.11
@schematics/angular             15.2.11
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.9.5

I am using nvm with Node version 16.13.2.

Could you follow my suggestions in this answer to test the SPA project is working or not?


Create a brand new spa project 2.  follow the suggestion in section1 .

